# Creating an event handler for C++ in nodejs addon

Tags: c++, node.js

I am new to native addons for Nodejs. I have a simple function in C++:

```cpp
void DoSomething(char arr[])
{
    //perform something
}
```

In Nodejs native addon I would like to do something like this:

```
addon.OnSomething((data)=> CallBackFunction(data))
```

Basically, I want to subscribe to an event when the `DoSomething` function is called. How can I do that? I read the documentation but I am not able to find a proper answer for this.